# How do I re-installing Xampp on BackBox?

Tags: software-installation, lamp, xampp

I was installing **Xampp** from terminal using `sudo apt-get install lamp-server`

My computer **shut down** while `lamp-server` was still **installing**.

I ran `sudo apt-get install lamp-server` again and it returned the following error:
`E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so BackBox is off-topic here as well. However, on http://unix.stackexchange.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)
2. type `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
3. Done! You can now run `sudo apt-get install lamp-server`!

Remember to mark this as an answer if I helped! It only takes a few seconds of your time and helps other users who have the same problem solve their issues. Thanks!